# Float in Plotly graph

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I already using matplotlin and started plotly but I found and interesting case,it make my year bcome float,I try read documentation but still didnt know whats wrong cause I already try it in matplotlib nothing wrong in matplotlib
[image: You can see my year become float]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('canada_per_capita_income (1).csv')
df.tail()


reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
y = df['per capita income (US$)']
reg.fit(df[['year']],y)

year = (2017,2018,2019,2020)
predict = reg.predict(np.array(year).reshape((len(year), 1)))
data = list(zip(year,predict))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Year', 'Prediction'])
df2.head()


fig = px.scatter(df2, x='Year', y='Prediction', opacity=0.65,
trendline='ols', trendline_color_override='darkblue',title='GDP Prediction',  log_x = 
True,log_y=False)
 fig.show()

 #my dataframe df2

 df2 = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'columns': ['Year', 'Prediction'], 'data': 
 [[2017, 
 38803.29886874952], [2018, 39631.763943972066], [2019, 40460.22901919484], 
 [2020, 41288.69409441762]]}
```

Comment: Can you show your dataframe `df2`?

Comment: Try converting your `year` list to a list of `Datetime` objects. I think Plotly is interpreting your years as integers, rather than dates.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I already updated maybe you can see

Comment: @JacobK when i see the data i think plotly see it as int64,I try change to date time but my year only year there is no month or day so I Find difficult to change it as datetime,maybe you have a stack overflow to solve it?

Comment: Could you also try converting the years to strings?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your x-axis has the attribute `log_x=True`. In my opinion the x-axis shouldn't be logarithmic. Try `log_x=False`

   ```
   fig = px.scatter(df2, x='Year', y='Prediction', trendline='ols', log_x=False, log_y=False)
   ```
2. If you update the layout of x-axis with `{'dtick': 1}` only values with a distance of 1 are shown on the x-axis

   ```
   fig.update_layout(xaxis={'dtick': 1})
   ```

**Complete code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/py/master/ML/1_linear_reg/Exercise/canada_per_capita_income.csv')

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
y = df['per capita income (US$)']
reg.fit(df[['year']], y) 

year = (2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)
predict = reg.predict(np.array(year).reshape((len(year), 1)))
data = list(zip(year,predict))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Year', 'Prediction'])

fig = px.scatter(df2, x='Year', y='Prediction', trendline='ols', log_x=False, log_y=False)
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'dtick': 1})
fig.show()
```

[image]